# undefined reference to 'uuid_generate' even though I use -luuid

Tags: c++, uuid

My test.cpp

```
#include <uuid/uuid.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  uuid_t id;
  uuid_generate(id);

  char *string = new char[100];
  uuid_unparse(id, string);

  std::cout << string << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I am using Ubuntu 14

I am running my test.cpp as ...

```
g++ -luuid test.cpp
```

and the output

```
test.cpp:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `uuid_generate'
test.cpp:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `uuid_unparse'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My g++ version:

```
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
```

and I already have uuid-dev installed.

```
sudo apt-get install uuid uuid-dev

uuid is already the newest version.
uuid-dev is already the newest version.
```

Comment: Did you try `g++ test.cpp -luuid`?

Comment: wow, it worked!  could you please add this as a answer with some explanation ? that I wlll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Order of linked libraries matters, you need to add the `-luuid` after the module it's referenced from:

```
g++ test.cpp -luuid
```

unless you are using the grouping options (`-Wl,--start-group`,`-Wl,--end-group`).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24675715/1413395) for more detail.